# SQL query - Generate a result by duplicate entries based on two foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I need an SQL query that duplicates the entries based on two foreign keys. To explain what I want to solve I have a simple example below. I have two tables, one with children and one with parents (the later isn't shown here). The children table have two references, one to the father and one to the mother in the parents table:

```
(Table: "Children")
Name     Father_ID  Mother_ID
=============================
Adam        2          4
Emma        1          3
George      5          6
```

There is a table called "Parents" where both Father_ID and Mother_ID points to. This means that fathers and mothers are listed in the same table.

Now I want an SQL query that generates this result:

```
Name     Parent_ID
==================
Adam        2
Adam        4
Emma        1
Emma        3
George      5
George      6
```

I.e. a result with duplicated entries - one for each parent.

How do I solve that?

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNION ALL`:

```
select Name, Father_ID from Children 
UNION ALL
select Name, Mother_ID from Children
```

Add `ORDER BY Name` if required.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT child_name, parent_id from children JoIN parenttable on Father_ID = parent_id 
UNION 
SELECT child_name, parent_id from children JoIN parenttable on Mother_ID = parent_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT children.[Name], Mother_ID AS ParentId FROM Children JOIN parents ON children.Mother_ID = parents.ID
UNION
SELECT children.[Name], Father_ID AS ParentId FROM Children JOIN parents ON children.Father_ID = parents.ID
```

Comment: Sorry, couple of other answers popped up since I refreshed, didn't realize others answered :)